# Matching strings that have common prefix and suffix but optional chars in the middle

Tags: regex

I want to check these forms by regularexpresion but i dont know how should i use 'or' | in it 
I have these forms which 'UC' is constant in all forms and after UC ,can be F or P or T or FL or FC or FA or PA and after letters there is a number with 3 digits .

UCF123

UCP123

UCT123

UCFL123

UCFC123

UCFA123

UCPA123

I have written this: `'/(?i)uc([tpf]?)|(f[lca]?)|(PA)\d\d\d/m'` but i doesnt work properly

Comment: Your examples are all uppercases but your regexp is lowercase. Isn't it the problem?

Comment: @LaurentG The OP is using the `(?i)` case insensitive flag, so no, maybe that's not the problem.

Comment: No I want the regex to be case insensitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
^UC(?:T|F[LCA]?|PA?)\d{3}$
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `^UC` - Start of string with `UC`
- `(?:T|F[LCA]?|PA?)` - Matches either only `T` OR only `F` or `F` followed by either `L` or `C` or `A` OR only `P` or `PA`
- `\d{3}` - followed by three digits
- `$` - End of string

Also, to help you clarify why your regex `(?i)uc([tpf]?)|(f[lca]?)|(PA)\d\d\d` didn't work was because, you needed to group the three alternations in your regex like this `(?i)uc(?:([tpf]?)|(f[lca]?)|(PA))\d\d\d` but even then it was slightly incorrect grouping, because then it would allow `UC123` which shouldn't be allowed as per your samples. The correct regex you need to use is given in my answer.

Also note, I have enabled case insensitivity flag in my demo which you can do easily by putting `i` after last slash as in your regex or inline by including this `(?i)` just before your regex like you already did in your regex in your post.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ReoAft/1)**

Comment: Note that this regex pattern isn't actually case insensitive.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: It is. Check the demo where case insensitive flag is ON. Let me add that in my post to make it more clear.

Comment: The regex was not case insensitive, i changed like this `(?i)^UC(?:T|F[LCA]?|PA?)\d{3}$` and it is case insensitive now

Comment: @ZaGol: I actually used the flag in the demo but yes you can include `(?i)` for inline enabling of case insensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/XzKdMT/1) might help you to match your inputs with less boundaries, if possible, only bounded from left using `UC`:

```
UC[A-Z]+[0-9]+
```

You could add more boundaries, if you wish, such as [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/yMUOc9/1/):

```
UC[FPTACL]+[1-3]+
```

Or [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/3K8dCc/1):

```
UC[FPTACL]{1,2}[1-3]{3}
```

Or maybe [this one](https://regex101.com/r/c8ZbeG/1), to cover more digits:

```
UC[FPTACL]{1,2}[0-9]{3}
```

You can see that you may not even need <kbd>|</kbd> (OR).